# how to know if we reached the max value of fs.file-max

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, lsof, openfire

on our linux rhel servers `fs.file-max` set with `100000`

```
sysctl -p | grep fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 100000
```

from my understanding the file-max kernel parameter refers to open file descriptors, and file-nr gives us the current number of open file descriptors. But lsof lists all open files, including files which are not using file descriptors – such as current working directories, memory mapped library files, and executable text files.

so back to my question

dose the following lsof  , really good indication that we reached the fs.file-max value?

```
lsof | wc -l
```

OR

```
[[ ` lsof | wc -l ` -gt 100000 ]] && echo "please increase the fs.file-max"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see global current open files:

cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

Comment: so can we do [[ ` cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr | awk '{print $1}' ` -gt  100000 ]] && echo please increase the fs.file-ma

Comment: is it really the indication to test if we reached the fs.file-max

Comment: Here some documentation about it https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/chap-oracle_9i_and_10g_tuning_guide-setting_file_handles

Comment: yes but this doc not answer on my question - dose  [[ ` cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr | awk '{print $1}' ` -gt 100000 ]] && echo please increase the fs.file-max is really the indication ?